# A question on starting out with scripts being ran with a usb

Tags: usb

So I am in a computer class and we are learning about scripts. During this class I asked my instructor if there was any way to basically plug in a usb thumb drive into a pc and automatically complete these following steps:

1. Open a specific applications file location
2. Copy said application
3. Paste said application onto the desktop
4. rename said application to the desired name

So yeah, was wondering if anyone could help me out or show me how to do this and such, I am quite new to all of this.

I haven't really tested that much, This is the first forum page I thought of coming too since my peers have had some good results with help from other users.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You haven't *done* anything for someone to help *with*.